# Need help to sort array list

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am very new to java and I need to create an array that stores numbers and then outputs the numbers in sorted list the mean mode and median.

can anyone tell me if I am on the right track so far with the code below

```
int number=0;

ArrayList<Integer> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scannerStream = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter list of numbers to Sort: (OR * TO  END LIST)");
while(!(listOfNumbers = br.readLine()).equals("*"))
     {

listOfNumbers = scannerStream.nextInt();
NumberList = listOfNumbers();
```

public Vector  listOfNumbersSort (int number) {

```
    for (int i=0; i<NumberList; i++) {

         int Sort = listOfNumbers();;


return Sort;

// returns the mean
public Vector<Integer>  listOfNumbersMean (int number){

    return mean;
} // end 

// returns the mode 
public Vector<Integer>  listOfNumbersMode (int number){

    return mode;
} // end 

// returns the median
public Vector<Integer>  listOfNumberMedian (int number){

    return median;
} // end
```

Thanks in advance for any help for advice provided

Comment: These all are method signatures, show us some implementation you tried to sort the list.

Comment: Ask yourself a question: "How many numbers the user need to enter?" and then create a control structure to implement this logic.  As of now you simply have **nothing**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
can anyone tell me if I am on the right track so far with the code below
```

Your method definitions does not look good. You are passing a number and expecting the sortedlistofnumbers.  Offcourse, if you already have a list, and you sorted it, and then if you get a new number and need to re-sort, then you can have the method signature as you have written, but not at the primary level.

The way you are accepting the list of number is not right. You need a loop. And when you use Arrays, since Arrays are fixed length, you should specify the size too.

see the below code for reference.

If you want to implement sorting in your way, there are various alogorithms like bubble sort.

Sorting Arrays

```
public class Sorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("How many numbers to sort ?");
        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        int numbers[] = new int[count];
        System.out.println("Enter list of numbers to Sort: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number");
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("List before sorting..");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        System.out.println("Sorted list");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sorting ArrayList**

```
public class SorterList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("How many numbers to sort ?");
        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter list of numbers to Sort: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number");
            numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println("List before sorting..");
        System.out.println(numbers);
        Collections.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println("Sorted list");
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to do custom sorting - say bubble sort algorithm,

```
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < (count - 1); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < count - i - 1; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]) // '> for ascending order'
                {
                    temp = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];
                    numbers[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collections.sort()` to sort an `ArrayList`.

Use `Arrays.sort()` to sort an array.

Comment: I don't think so because OP has defined other methods also.

Comment: Which is available in Java's source :D